# Stuck lifter; roller pin backing out

Tags: ford, escort, valve-lifter

I've got a 1.9L Ford Escort.  It has a stuck lifter.  When trying to remove it, it'll only come up a very short distance and then stop.  It appears that the pin that holds in the roller at the bottom of the lifter has started backing out, preventing removal.  Trying to remove the cam and extract the lifter from below won't work either.  The stuck lifter is in the way of cam removal.  Help!

Comment: Can you break or separate the camshaft, then removing the pieces get to the lifter? Another thought is if the pin moves, then stand the block on its end which may allow the pin to slide back into place allowing the lifter to come out.

Comment: What year is the engine you're working on?

Comment: The lifter right next to the one that's stuck was easily removed.  Looking down into this hole, we can only see & access just the bottom edge of the pin in the stuck lifter.  There is very little room to work.  Using a flat dental tool, we tried pushing it back with no success.  This is a 1996 Ford Escort 1.9L.  No, can't separate the camshaft.

Comment: Can you try something a little more substantial to push it back in, like a screwdriver? Also, ensure there's no pressure on the lifter itself. If it still doesn't want to push back into where it belongs, I'm wondering if there's some damage to the roller pin or trunnion.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.. modifying a small mirror, we could confirm that when the roller pin backed out, it started cutting a channel in the bore.  That's why it couldn't be lifted out nor could you turn it.  Now the concern is that since it doesn't move up but a small fraction, the camshaft is most likely very worn or damaged on that spot.  We've decided to replace the head.